# Parsing issues in Confluent S3 sink connector [serialization error]

Tags: apache-kafka, jackson, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I am using confluent s3 sink connector with confluent kafka code for base kafka-connect(v5.2.1).

Originally, MySQL cdc is written as JSON(using maxwell) into a kafka topic (no schema written).
This kafka connector reads data from the above apache kafka cluster and writes it to s3.

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

I am using distributed connector with following connector config:

```
{
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
"behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
"s3.region": "ap-southeast-1",
"flush.size": "1000",
"schema.compatibility": "NONE",
"topics": "audit",
"tasks.max": "3",
"s3.part.size": "5242880",
"timezone": "UTC",
"locale": "en_US_POSIX",
"retry.backoff.ms": "100",
"format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
"partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
"name": "s3-sink-connector-um-cdc-events",
"storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
"s3.bucket.name": "tickledb/prod/audit",
"timestamp.extractor": "Record",
"s3.retry.backoff.ms": "100",
"rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "10000"
```

}

While this works in general, I keep seeing this error.

```
task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:344)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (byte[])"3d5b807d-a6c7-43da-bbcc-d40efe9753a7"; line: 1, column: 3]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (byte[])"3d5b807d-a6c7-43da-bbcc-d40efe9753a7"; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:638)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1635)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1375)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:830)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4042)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2571)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:342)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:464)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:320)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It appears parsing error in Jackson. This data is coming from cdc events of a MySQL . So it is not possible to change the data in these (without a disruptive change). If kafka is accepting a json data, it should be legit for kafka-connector also.

Comment: What `value.converter` are you using? Are all the records on the source topic valid JSON?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt updated my question to include this info. I'm using Json everywhere

Comment: Error seems to suggest your data is only a string (you've mentioned the values are CDC events, but what about the keys?). The S3 sink doesn't write record keys, so don't use json converter for it

Comment: @OneCricketeercan you please elaborate on "S3 sink doesn't write record keys" part? As I mentioned, this connector was running for quite some time and then I faced this error. What you mentioned about string, one possibility could be the message was string. But Maxwell, as per their doc, writes json always. Anyway, I'll just remove key.converter

Answer (score 2):

I have not found the reason for failure but I updated the connector config to prevent tasks from going into "FAILED" state and also capture the actual messages which cause failure.

Updated config field

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "audit_dlq_sink_00",
"errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
"errors.log.include.messages": "true",
"errors.log.include.messages": "true",
"errors.log.enable": "true",
```

With this updated config, event parsing does not stop my tasks. It sends the messages into the configured DLQ. However, it does not send actual error messages into DLQ, only message which failed to parse.